# MySQL "delayed commit ok done" and performance

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I am using AURORA MySQL on AWS. When I run `show Processlist` I see lots of `delayed commit ok done`

I want to ask that does it hinder in performance? If Yes, how dO I imrpove it?

I am using `PyMySQL`, a Python based library and I do use `.commit` after each `INSERTS` and `UPDATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your code. Check this: http://datavirtualizer.com/delayed-commit-ok-initiated-aurora-mysql/

It's an internal mechanism used in aurora to do commits. It's specific to aurora. It probably doesn't have much of a performance impact since AWS chose this as the commit mechanism & aurora is touted as being as powerful as MySQL.

Comment: is it possible that the data committed by this delayed commit are visible by other connections after a second or so in a database with many queries per second?

Comment: The data committed by this "delayed commit" has already been committed - in the mysql sense - so it won't be a violation of any isolation level for it to be visible. In fact, it should be visible to other transactions (depending on their isolation level)